# Problemas al visualizar el contenido de un xml en formato json usando clob

Tags: json, oracle, plsql, clob

Estoy probando el código para consultar una tabla, obtengo el resultado como XML
lo convierto en formato JSON, y lo muestro en la pantalla para realizar pruebas.
Mi problema es que, al mostrar el JSON en formato varchar (con GetStringVal)
funciona bien, pero si el resultado es extenso, lo muestro como Clob (con GetClobVal).
En este caso, la cadena que se muestra incluye el literal "& quot;" cuando debería
mostrar comillas dobles

A continuación, muestro la función que se aplica para convertir el xml a json,
seguido de un bloque anónimo con las pruebas realizadas sobre un pequeño xml.

Mi base de datos es Oracle 12.1

Gracias por su interés en ayudarme.

```
--Define a function with the XSLT to convert the XML to JSON
SET DEFINE OFF
  CREATE OR REPLACE 
  FUNCTION style_sheet_json 
  RETURN VARCHAR2 IS
    l_xslt VARCHAR2 ( 32000 );
  BEGIN
    l_xslt := '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<!--
  Copyright (c) 2006, Doeke Zanstra
  All rights reserved.

  Redistribution and use in source and binary forms, with or without modification,
  are permitted provided that the following conditions are met:

  Redistributions of source code must retain the above copyright notice, this
  list of conditions and the following disclaimer. Redistributions in binary
  form must reproduce the above copyright notice, this list of conditions and the
  following disclaimer in the documentation and/or other materials provided with
  the distribution.

  Neither the name of the dzLib nor the names of its contributors may be used to
  endorse or promote products derived from this software without specific prior
  written permission.

  THIS SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED BY THE COPYRIGHT HOLDERS AND CONTRIBUTORS "AS IS" AND
  ANY EXPRESS OR IMPLIED WARRANTIES, INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO, THE IMPLIED
  WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY AND FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE ARE DISCLAIMED.
  IN NO EVENT SHALL THE COPYRIGHT OWNER OR CONTRIBUTORS BE LIABLE FOR ANY DIRECT,
  INDIRECT, INCIDENTAL, SPECIAL, EXEMPLARY, OR CONSEQUENTIAL DAMAGES (INCLUDING,
  BUT NOT LIMITED TO, PROCUREMENT OF SUBSTITUTE GOODS OR SERVICES; LOSS OF USE,
  DATA, OR PROFITS; OR BUSINESS INTERRUPTION) HOWEVER CAUSED AND ON ANY THEORY OF
  LIABILITY, WHETHER IN CONTRACT, STRICT LIABILITY, OR TORT (INCLUDING NEGLIGENCE OR
  OTHERWISE) ARISING IN ANY WAY OUT OF THE USE OF THIS SOFTWARE, EVEN IF ADVISED OF
  THE POSSIBILITY OF SUCH DAMAGE.
-->

  <xsl:output indent="no" omit-xml-declaration="yes" method="text" encoding="UTF-8" media-type="text/x-json"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
  <!--contant-->
  <xsl:variable name="d">0123456789</xsl:variable>

  <!-- ignore document text -->
  <xsl:template match="text()[preceding-sibling::node() or following-sibling::node()]"/>

  <!-- string -->
  <xsl:template match="text()">
    <xsl:call-template name="escape-string">
      <xsl:with-param name="s" select="."/>
    </xsl:call-template>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- Main template for escaping strings; used by above template and for object-properties
       Responsibilities: placed quotes around string, and chain up to next filter, escape-bs-string -->
  <xsl:template name="escape-string">
    <xsl:param name="s"/>
    <xsl:text>"</xsl:text>
    <xsl:call-template name="escape-bs-string">
      <xsl:with-param name="s" select="$s"/>
    </xsl:call-template>
    <xsl:text>"</xsl:text>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- Escape the backslash (\) before everything else. -->
  <xsl:template name="escape-bs-string">
    <xsl:param name="s"/>
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="contains($s,''\'')">
        <xsl:call-template name="escape-quot-string">
          <xsl:with-param name="s" select="concat(substring-before($s,''\''),''\\'')"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
        <xsl:call-template name="escape-bs-string">
          <xsl:with-param name="s" select="substring-after($s,''\'')"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:call-template name="escape-quot-string">
          <xsl:with-param name="s" select="$s"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- Escape the double quote ("). -->
  <xsl:template name="escape-quot-string">
    <xsl:param name="s"/>
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="contains($s,'';'')">
        <xsl:call-template name="encode-string">
          <xsl:with-param name="s" select="concat(substring-before($s,'';''),''&quot;'')"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
        <xsl:call-template name="escape-quot-string">
          <xsl:with-param name="s" select="substring-after($s,'';'')"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:call-template name="encode-string">
          <xsl:with-param name="s" select="$s"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- Replace tab, line feed and/or carriage return by its matching escape code. Can''t escape backslash
       or double quote here, because they don''t replace characters (; becomes \t), but they prefix
       characters (\ becomes \\). Besides, backslash should be seperate anyway, because it should be
       processed first. This function can''t do that. -->
  <xsl:template name="encode-string">
    <xsl:param name="s"/>
    <xsl:choose>
      <!-- tab -->
      <xsl:when test="contains($s,'';'')">
        <xsl:call-template name="encode-string">
          <xsl:with-param name="s" select="concat(substring-before($s,'';''),''\t'',substring-after($s,'';''))"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
      </xsl:when>
      <!-- line feed -->
      <xsl:when test="contains($s,'';'')">
        <xsl:call-template name="encode-string">
          <xsl:with-param name="s" select="concat(substring-before($s,'';''),''\n'',substring-after($s,'';''))"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
      </xsl:when>
      <!-- carriage return -->
      <xsl:when test="contains($s,'';'')">
        <xsl:call-template name="encode-string">
          <xsl:with-param name="s" select="concat(substring-before($s,'';''),''\r'',substring-after($s,'';''))"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise><xsl:value-of select="$s"/></xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- number (no support for javascript mantise) -->
  <xsl:template match="text()[not(string(number())=''NaN'')]">
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- boolean, case-insensitive -->
  <xsl:template match="text()[translate(.,''TRUE'',''true'')=''true'']">true</xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="text()[translate(.,''FALSE'',''false'')=''false'']">false</xsl:template>

  <!-- item:null -->
  <xsl:template match="*[count(child::node())=0]">
    <xsl:call-template name="escape-string">
      <xsl:with-param name="s" select="local-name()"/>
    </xsl:call-template>
    <xsl:text>:null</xsl:text>
    <xsl:if test="following-sibling::*">,</xsl:if>
    <xsl:if test="not(following-sibling::*)">}</xsl:if> <!-- MBR 30.01.2010: added this line as it appeared to be missing from stylesheet -->
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- object -->
  <xsl:template match="*" name="base">
    <xsl:if test="not(preceding-sibling::*)">{</xsl:if>
    <xsl:call-template name="escape-string">
      <xsl:with-param name="s" select="name()"/>
    </xsl:call-template>
    <xsl:text>:</xsl:text>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="child::node()"/>
    <xsl:if test="following-sibling::*">,</xsl:if>
    <xsl:if test="not(following-sibling::*)">}</xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- array -->
  <xsl:template match="*[count(../*[name(../*)=name(.)])=count(../*) and count(../*)&gt;1]">
    <xsl:if test="not(preceding-sibling::*)">[</xsl:if>
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="not(child::node())">
        <xsl:text>null</xsl:text>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="child::node()"/>
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
    <xsl:if test="following-sibling::*">,</xsl:if>
    <xsl:if test="not(following-sibling::*)">]</xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- convert root element to an anonymous container -->
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>';

    RETURN ( l_xslt );

  END style_sheet_json;
/


DECLARE
l_xml XMLTYPE;
l_json XMLTYPE;
BEGIN

l_xml := XMLTYPE (
'<ROWSET>
 <ROW>
  <ID>4</ID>
  <DENOPAIS>Afganistán</DENOPAIS>
 </ROW>
</ROWSET>');

--Las 2 impresiones siguientes muestran lo mismo, el xml tal cual
dbms_output.put_line ( 'Shows xml as varchar');
dbms_output.put_line ( l_xml.GetStringVal());

dbms_output.put_line ('');
dbms_output.put_line ( 'Shows xml as clob');
dbms_output.put_line ( l_xml.GetClobVal());

dbms_output.put_line ('');
dbms_output.put_line ( 'Converting xml to json format...');
l_json := l_xml.TRANSFORM ( XMLTYPE ( style_sheet_json () ) );

dbms_output.put_line ('');
dbms_output.put_line ( 'Shows json as varchar');
dbms_output.put_line ( l_json.GetStringVal());

dbms_output.put_line ('');
dbms_output.put_line ( 'Shows json as clob');
dbms_output.put_line ( l_json.GetClobVal());

end;
```

Answer (score 0):

El compañero que aportó la solución indica que comentó sobre esto hace pocos años [aquí](https://odieweblog.wordpress.com/2014/11/16/xmltransform-tips-and-tricks/).

Dado que el método **TRANSFORM** devuelve una instancia de **XMLType**, existen algunas 
discrepancias cuando el método de salida de la hoja de estilo se establece en texto.

¿Cuál es el comportamiento correcto en esta situación? No escapar las entidades de 
caracteres para que aparezcan como texto claro, o mantenerlas tal como están para 
que el contenido **XML** siga siendo válido.

Las soluciones provisionales que se mencionan en la publicación referenciada se aplican 
a **Oracle 11.2**, y parece que el comportamiento ha cambiado un poco en **12c**.

Aún así, se pueden usar enfoques similares para obtener la salida **CLOB** esperada:

```
DECLARE    
  l_xsl    xmltype := xmltype(style_sheet_json);  
  l_xml    xmltype;  
  l_json   xmltype;  
  l_out    clob;  

BEGIN  
  l_xml := XMLTYPE (  
'<ROWSET>  
<ROW>  
  <ID>4</ID>  
  <DENOPAIS>Afganistán</DENOPAIS>  
</ROW>  
</ROWSET>');  

  dbms_output.put_line('Using explicit conversion of character entities :');  
  l_json := l_xml.transform(l_xsl);  
  l_out := dbms_xmlgen.convert(l_json.getclobval(), dbms_xmlgen.ENTITY_DECODE);  
  dbms_output.put_line(l_out);  

  dbms_output.new_line;  
  dbms_output.put_line('Using SQL function XMLTransform :');  
  select xmltransform(l_xml, l_xsl)  
  into l_json  
  from dual;                

  l_out := l_json.getclobval;                
  dbms_output.put_line(l_out);                

  dbms_output.new_line;                
  dbms_output.put_line('Using SQL functions XMLTransform and XMLCast :');  
  select xmlcast(xmltransform(l_xml, l_xsl) as clob)   
  into l_out                
  from dual;                

  dbms_output.put_line(l_out);                

END;                
/                

Using explicit conversion of character entities :      
{"ROWSET":{"ROW":{"ID":4,"DENOPAIS":"Afganistán"}}}    

Using SQL function XMLTransform :                
{"ROWSET":{"ROW":{"ID":4,"DENOPAIS":"Afganistán"}}}    

Using SQL functions XMLTransform and XMLCast :         
{"ROWSET":{"ROW":{"ID":4,"DENOPAIS":"Afganistán"}}}    

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```